# How to create a Hero Image with form beside it and make full-width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to know how to develop a hero section and put booking form beside each and make it scale on all screen sizes.

This how I want the hero section to look on the page. Trying to find out different examples and ideas.

Design Concept:

[image]

**This what it looks in the browser:**

[image]

**Hero Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../sass/main.scss';
import { Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import FindSpaceFormComponment from '../layouts/findspaceform'; // image is defined but never used...
import Hero from "../../src/images/1421x1126.png"; 


const HeroStyle = {
    width: "1421px",
    height: "100vh",
    backgroundImage: `url(${Hero})`
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Container fluid={true}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="2" lg="2" xl="2" mb="2">
                            <div className="OnTop">
                                <FindSpaceFormComponment />
                            </div>
                        </Col>

                        <Col md="6" lg="6" xl="6" mb="6">
                            <div className="ImgBg VidBg" style={ HeroStyle }> 
                            </div>
                        </Col> 
                    </Row>
                </Container> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Hero Component CSS**

```
.ImgBg {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -96px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Booking Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../sass/main.scss';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="FindSpaceForm">
                <h1 className="MainTitle">Find a Place To Get Together</h1>
                <form onSubmit="">
                    <div className="FormChild">
                        <label>Where</label>
                        <input placeholder="Anywhere" type="text" value="" onChange="" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="FormChild">
                        <div className="FlexInline PFM">
                            <label>Book-In</label>
                          <select className="Idjefm329 style3w948">
                            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
                            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
                          </select>
                         </div>
                         <div className="FlexInline">
                            <label>Book-Out</label>
                        <select className="style3w948">
                            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
                            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="FormChild">
                        <label>Attendees</label>
                            <select className="style3w948">
                            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
                            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div className="FormChild">
                        <button className="book-now" type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Booking Component CSS**

```
.OnTop {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-top: 7em;
  margin-bottom: 7em;
  width: 191vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.OnTop .MainTitle {
  font-size: 4.75rem;
  width: 474px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.OnTop .FindSpaceForm {
  background: black;
  padding: .9em 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.OnTop .FindSpaceForm form .FormChild {
  padding-bottom: 1.3em;
  width: 100%;
}

.OnTop .FindSpaceForm form .FormChild .book-now {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  width: 130px;
}

.OnTop .FindSpaceForm form label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.OnTop .FindSpaceForm form input, .OnTop .FindSpaceForm form button, .OnTop .FindSpaceForm form select, .OnTop .FindSpaceForm form option {
  height: 73px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest structuring your questions more in a way that'll earn you help. This was not a React question as it's mostly just HTML/CSS and really has nothing to do with React. Your first role here would have been to figure out how you want your layout to adapt to different screen sizes and show that in the question. Also to maybe include a codepen demo since it's about layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of layout will definitely not work for all screen sizes based on your request so we may ask. Is this really a CSS/HTML question or a design issue? For design, here's how I'd go about designing that layout mobile and desktop:

[image: mobile design demo]
[image: desktop design demo]

So the simple answer to your question is use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and I wouldn't tag this as a React question since the React part of it mostly negligible. It's a layout problem.

I also went ahead to create a quick code demo of how you might achieve this with HTML and CSS [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/josephrexme/full/XWrKQjK)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
h2{margin: 10px 0}
a{text-decoration: none; color: #776}
.hero{
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 240px;
  header{
    display: flex;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: none;
  }
  .hamburger{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid medium #776;
    outline: none;
    &::before, &::after{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 40px;
      border-top: solid medium #776;
    }
    &::before{
      top: -12px;
    }
    &::after{
      bottom: -6px;
    }
    @media(min-width: 620px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  nav{
    display: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    a{ margin-left: 15px; display: inline-block; }
    @media(min-width: 620px) {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  .backdrop{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    @media (min-width: 720px) {
      left: 20%;
    }
  }
}
.content{
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  h1{margin: 30px 0;}
  @media(min-width: 720px) {
    text-align: right;
    h1{
      margin: 50px 0;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  }
}
.btn{
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background: #06a;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #ddd;
}
.form{
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: #089;
  @media(min-width: 720px) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <header>
    <h2>Logo</h2>
    <button class="hamburger"></button>
    <nav>
      <a href="/">Menu One</a>
      <a href="/">Menu Two</a>
      <a href="/">Menu Three</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Some catchy title here</h1>
    <button class="btn">Call to action</button>
    <form class="form">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
</div>
<p>Bottom content</p>
```

Comment: You were correct, I forgot to add a mobile view of the design. thank for show different way developers would develop the design concept.